# Insert into when a page load Session();

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

When the page open, I would like to insert 3 values into this page, which are primary key of Genres,Artists,RecordCompanies before this form and will be foreign key, into the this table, which is Albums.

my tables are

Albums-------------

AlbumID Primary Key

ReleaseDate

RecordCompanyID Foreign Key

ArtistID Foreign Key

GenreID Foreign Key

RecordCompanies------------------------------

RecodCompanyID Priamry Key

RecordComapnyName

Genres---------------------------

GenreID Primary Key

Genre

Artist------------------------------------------

ArtistID Primary Key

ArtistName

```
namespace WebApplication6
{
    public partial class WebForm15 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["genreid"] != null && Session["artistid"] != null && Session["recordcompanyid"] != null)
            {
                Label7.Visible = true;
                Label7.Text = "Welcome : " + Session["genreid"] + "Welcome : " + Session["artistid"] + "Welcome : " + Session["recordcompanyid"];
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/BenEManagementGenre.aspx");
            }


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {






                String Artists = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FleetManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Artists);

                int artistid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["artistid"]);
                int genreid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["genreid"]);
                int recodcompanyid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["recodcompanyid"]);


                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Albums] (GenreID,ArtistID,RecordCompanyID)
               VALUES (@Genre, @Artist,@RecordCompany);" + "select scope_Identity() as ID", con);



                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", artistid);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", genreid);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordCompany", recodcompanyid);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();
                int ID = -1;


                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    ID = int.Parse(rd["ID"].ToString());

                }
                rd.Close();
                con.Close();

                Session.Add("albumid", ID);

            }
```

The error says

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "fk_AlbumsRecordCompanyID". The conflict occurred in database
>   "KazuTest", table "dbo.RecordCompanies", column 'RecordCompanyID'.

In my theory, when I open the page, I inserted to 3 values which are foreign keys, so I already inserted Foreign keys.  so why this error is showing up?

Comment: What is the value being inserted for the `RecordCompanyID` column?  Is there a matching key in the `RecordCompanies` table?  The error states that there isn't, and I'm inclined to believe it.

Comment: have you at least tried to step through the code using the `debugger` also make sure that your keys are not set for Auto Generate also the error message is telling you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: As a side note unless you are using stored procedures (which I would recommend) you need to be careful using AddWithValue. It can get datatypes incorrect and cause some ugly challenges. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how you add the parameters:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", artistid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", genreid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordCompany", recodcompanyid);
```

You are putting the ArtistId in the GenreID column and the GenreId in the ArtistID column. In this way the foreing keys constraints are not respected.

The correct versione should be:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", genreid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", artistid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordCompany", recodcompanyid);
```

Comment: I have been dealing this issue for a long time so I switching around, It was my mistake I fixed like you said, but it still causing same error I do not know why.                      I tested on SQLServer like this 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Albums]
           (
           [RecordCompanyID]
           ,[ArtistID]
           ,[GenreID]
           )
     VALUES
           (
           1, 
           1,
           1
           )
GO I could insert but on .Net still causing same error, do you know why?

Comment: @Kazu have you tried to debug the code to get the value of the two properties? Once you do that, check if they exist in the respective tables.